# stoppropagation within function confusion on jquery

Tags: jquery

```
function myfunction(){

    $('.link').click(e){
        e.stoppropagation()
        alert();
    }

}
```

Is this the correct usage of stoppropagation? myfunction still fired when the click trigger().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's are some sytax errors. Please check with updated code as shown below:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.link').click(function(e){
       e.stopPropagation();
       alert();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There two problems in your code.

1.) Jquery is handling click event of `'.link'` then there is no need of `myfunction()`.

2.) e.stoppropagation() should be e.stopPropagation(); (Javascript is case sensitive)

**PROPER CODE :**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.link').click(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    alert();
  });
});
```

**EDIT :**

More information on `stopPropagation` is here :- http://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/

Answer (score 0):

You have syntax error.Edit it like this

```
$(".link").click(function(event){
event.stopPropagation();
alert(1);
//return false;
});
```

You can either create an object inside function like `event` and call stopPropagation() method or you can write `return false` statement instead of the above mentioned object

Comment: Hope you understand the difference